# In Flutter, how do I find a widget in some (x,y) position?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Given some (x,y) coordinates, in logical pixels, relative to:

1. The top-left of the screen.
2. The top-left of some Container.

How can I know which widget is in that position?

Comment: This is a relatively expensive operation. Are you sure you want to do that ?

Comment: Yep. Why would I ask otherwise?

Comment: @RémiRousselet, what makes this an expensive operation?

Comment: @Suragch this basically goes through all widgets and check them individually

Comment: @MarcG because depending on what you truly want to do, you may not need this.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm sure I want/need this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are after the `hitTest` method  in `RenderBox` class. As per the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/hitTest.html)

> Returns true if the given point is contained in this render object or
>   one of its descendants. Adds any render objects that contain the point
>   to the given hit test result.

So you can get the RenderBox instance of the widget from the key context

```
GlobalKey key = new GlobalKey();
//your stuff
final RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject()
// do box.hitTest
```

Comment: what if `box` is inside a TabView ? it's result is not true when switching to another tab and return; it returns different values